# Error: No resource identifier found for Android Support Design

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin for the first time. Currently I am only working on the android project. I have installed the Android Support Design package trought the NuGet Packet Manager. My goal is to use some of these provided elements like `BottomNavigationView`. My problem here is, that when I try to build it, I get this error: `No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package 'android'`

Here is a printscreen of my `Main.axml`. As you can see, Visual Studio seems like can not find any elements of the Support Design Package. Am I missing something?

[image: Main.axml code snippet]

Answer (score 0):

> I get this error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package 'android'

You should firstly be able to create a folder named "menu" under "Resources" folder and place your menu layout under this folder for example:

[image]

Then I saw you already added `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your root `RelativeLayout`, then you will need to change your code `android:menu="..."` to `app:menu="..."`. Here is an example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header" />
```

Then you may clean and rebuild your app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The rename from `android` to `app` helped to resolve this issue, but i got another one now: `Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`

Comment: @Sylnois, can you please check if the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition` package has been installed to your project?

Comment: Yes, it is installed!

Comment: @Sylnois, try to clean and rebuild your project, if it still doesn't help, try  to close your VS and reload your project.